# How can I use third party 'libraries' in python?

Tags: python, eclipse, libraries

**Disclaimer**: This is a very basic question, but keep in mind I come from a Microsoft background, and I've programmed mostly in .NET with Visual Studio (this may help you help me with analogies perhaps)

---

I started programming a little python for the fun of it, so I downloaded [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), and installed [PyDev](http://pydev.org/).

I reached a point where I needed to parse a date, and I found an alternive to [time.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) that seemed interesting. That alternative was [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).

I went ahead and downloaded it, but I had problems when I tried to use it.
Apparently [the download](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-2f49784d6b27bae60cde1cff6a535663cf87497b) includes source files, and I had absolutely no idea how to use it in my "project" in eclipse.

So my very basic questions:

- Do I need to include the source files directly with my files? Perhaps in a subdirectory? How would I use it in my code (how do I *import* them in my .py file)?
- Do I need to "build" (make?) them and reference them? How? How do you "compile" something like that in windows?
- Am I totally missing some important point?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: In addition to the answers here, read http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I went ahead and downloaded it, but I
>   had problems when I tried to use it.
>   Apparently the download includes
>   source files, and I had absolutely no
>   idea how to use it in my "project" in
>   eclipse.

you should use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) in your line of command type :

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

this command will do all the thing for you it will download and install the library 
automatically. if you don't have `pip` refer to the documentation above to see how you should install it

> Do I need to include the source files
>   directly with my files? Perhaps in a
>   subdirectory? How would I use it in my
>   code (how do I import them in my .py
>   file)?

if you have used pip like above no need , you should now just `import dateutil` in your scripts to use it:

```
import dateutil
```

> Do I need to "build" (make?) them and
>   reference them? How? How do you
>   "compile" something like that in
>   windows?

everything is done with pip (magic isn't it :) )

> Am I totally missing some important
>   point?

Yes python is cool, easy and fun , forget about make ,make install ... Everything in python is easy installable.

And for the love of G.. please use pip (it's an order from the [BDFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum)).

[image]

hope this can help:)

Answer (score 1):

The tarball you downloaded had a Makefile in it, so just use that:

```
make install
```

Then, in the file where you want to use something from the new module, import it like any other Python module:

```
import dateutil
```

Comment: I tried this, but I showed the import line as an error -- you need to import the "directory name"? It had several .py files inside, it just imports everything and I can use any function inside the dateutil dir?

Comment: pretty much, `from dateutil import parser` will let you use `parser.parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

> - Do I need to include the source files directly with my files? Perhaps in a subdirectory? How would I use it in my code (how do I import them in my .py file)?

You just need to import the `py` file. For example, if your module is called `x`, you need to do a `import x`

> - Do I need to "build" (make?) them and reference them? How? How do you "compile" something like that in windows?

No. Just do an `import x` and a `x.pyc` file will be created. This is the byte-compiled version of the module `x`.

> - Am I totally missing some important point?
>     Download the `python-dateutil` and extract it to a directory.

Then you need to do a (might require appropriate permissions on Windows. Read more [here](http://docs.python.org/install/))

`python setup.py install`

This will automatically install (and thus copy) all the module files to a path where the Python interpreter can find them. You can find that by using: `import sys` and then `print sys.path`. These will be the locations where the interpreter will search for the modules.

After installation, start your interpreter and then try `import dateutil`. If all is well, the module should be imported.

When you need to distribute your application, all the necessary modules will be need to be packaged along. Note that you just need to include the `py` files and not `pyc`.

For a better understanding of packaging the source files, you need to read about the `disutitls` module. [Here](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html) is the link.

Answer (score 1):

The tarball you downloaded had a Makefile in it, so just use that:

make install
Then, in the file where you want to use something from the new module, import it like any other Python module:

import dateutil

Answer (score 0):

Extract the archive and execute:

```
python setup.py install
```

[Here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2/inst/trivial-install.html#SECTION000120000000000000000) is details.

Comment: What and where exactly would this "install" the module?

Comment: As I know it has been installed with Python. And you must execute this command in the direcotory where you extracted package.

Comment: "What and where exactly would this "install" the module?"  Check the Python `site` package documentation.  Check where Python is currently installed.

Comment: @demas I don't have Eclipse, so I followed your method. It seemed to have worked, but is there anything else I must do?