# how to import third party libraries in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python, as like in Perl CPAN modules, is there anyway to download and import libraries in Python for the functionality  which are not supported by the in built library modules?

Comment: There is. What problems did you face trying it out?

Comment: try `pip` or `easy_install`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109206/how-can-i-use-third-party-libraries-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Yes there is. More detail would require knowledge of which modules you want.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the **`easy_install`** module. As long as you have the admin privilege, you can download useful modules from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). This repository has the modules that most of us python developers develop and allow its open-source usage. The syntax and semantics to use `easy_install` can be found [here](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html#using-easy-install).

You can import these library modules in you code seamlessly.

Comment: `pip` is recommended over `easy_install` whenever possible. See the [python packaging guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps:

1. Search and download easy_install
2. Unzip it.
3. python setup.py install
4. Setup path in environment
5. You are ready to go using easy_install modulename

For some strange reason, if you are on windows, you may face a dll missing issue. I don't remember the name of dll. So instead of searching for solution, just install Visual Studio 2008 express ( Visual C++ ). Yes I mentioned strange. If you face any issue, feel free to ask.